# How to setup config file? Instructions in the docs don't seem to work

Tags: automated-tests, puppeteer

Puppetter's global cache directory works but i want to setup .cache directory.

So, I am trying to set the cache using the recommended methods as described in the [docs](https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration/#:%7E:text=(reinstall%20puppeteer%20to%20take%20effect)%3A). But unexpectedly reinstalling puppeteer doesnt create .cache folder in the project folder or in the parent folder. Below is my config file.

```
// .puppeteerrc.cjs

const { join } = require("path");

console.log("Puppeteer config loaded");
console.log("Puppeteer cache directory:", join(__dirname, ".cache", "puppeteer"));


module.exports = {
  // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
  cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, ".cache", "puppeteer"),
};
```

how do I setup config file which pupperteer understands?

- I have tried reinstalling puppeteer which did NOT work.
- I have tried manually creating .cache folder which did NOT work.

Answer (score 1):

It works after reinstall Puppetter.

Remove package.json, package-lock.json and folder node_modules.

Then install Puppetter again.